# Does $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2+y^4}{x+y^2}$ exist, and equal $0$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I just need a simple yes or no answer to see if my answer is in line with a consensus. Does the limit 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2+y^4}{x+y^2}$$ exist? I think it does, and the limit is 0.

Comment: "I think it does, and the limit is $0$". Can you write down your reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note the denominator is equal to zero along the parabola $x = y^2$. That's going to make it impossible for the limit to exist.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand it better if I think of the limit in terms of polar coordinates. There world be a cos(theta) remaining in the denominator, and since that varies, the limit could not possibly exist.

Comment: @shmiggens: The $\cos\theta$ in the denominator can be viewed as relevant, but be careful not to apply that reasoning to say $\dfrac{x^6+y^8}{x^2+y^4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Along the path $x=-y^2+y^5$, 
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^2+y^4}{x+y^2} = \frac{2y^4+y^{10}-2y^5}{y^5}\rightarrow \infty.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x, y)\rightarrow (0, 0)} \frac{x^2+y^4}{x+y^2}
\end{align*}
does not exist.